# Magento 2 Customer Rest Api Token error for some users [weird problem]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

We have a mobile app for magento 2 which we communicate with magento 2 server using Rest api.

Our intent is to get customer access token by below request

```
https://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token/
Post request
body 
{
    "username":"user12@ymail.com",
    "password":"user123"
}
Response
{
    "message": "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."
}
```

The issue is not for all users only for a few users.One of which is our demo user account. We can't find any difference between working accounts and nonworking accounts. 
Using same credentials we able to login in front end without any issues. The issue is when trying via rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Check table `oauth_token_request_log` for locked users. This is a know issue. Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317539/5827