# You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled:customer login

Tags: magento2, customer, api, customer-account, token

When I try to load **/rest/v1/integration/customer/token**, passing username and password in the body, it shows below error:

> {
>       "message": "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.",
>       "trace": "#0 [internal function]: Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService->createCustomerAccessToken('mallika.sarna@h...',
>   'bWFsbGlrYS5zYXJ...')\n#1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(330):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#3
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#4
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#5
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#6
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#7
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#8
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#9
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#10
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoshop/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#11
>   {main}" }

Comment: please check with that customer account may be its disabled.

Comment: Then how can I enable it?

Comment: goto admin and than check with customer

Comment: please explain the steps

Comment: Mr. Lord - Just run setup upgrade and clear the cache sometimes that happens, I was stuck in the same situation once.

Comment: Let me know if above solution doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will want to post to retrieve a token.  You will need to post an admin username and login.

```
POST https://somewebsite.com/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "Password123"
}
```

The response will provide a valid bearer token.  Use this token to begin making the API requests:

```
GET https://somewebsite.com/rest/all/V1/orders/12345
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer uxn42pnqksxh1mnwarj0pqprtwyg3hfn
```

Comment: Actually,ii wanted to get an customer token..not admin token

Answer (score 1):

It's on old question but still it might be helpful since I got same kind of issues. It turns out Magento keeps track of failed login attempt trough API. And for me this was hard to solve/find. That's why I am posting it here.

So check the `oauth_token_request_log` table for entries. So in development phase this can occur very fast of course. The credit goes to Muhsin Keloth form this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959142/2190322

tl;dr

`DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;`

Answer (score 0):

To get a customer token,

```
POST https://somewebsite.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "username": "username",
  "password": "Password123"
}
```

You can test with curl:

```
curl https://somewebsite.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"username":"username","password":"password"}'
```

If under Windows, you will need to use double quote and escape double quotes in data correctly:

```
curl https://somewebsite.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
```